# Trying to Share from both Facebook and Twitter in a Row

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)shareButton
{
    if(self.isTwitter.on)
       [self shareTwitter];
    if(self.isFacebook.on)
        [self shareFacebook];
}
```

The methods called work separately. If I try to run them together, however, the Twitter method runs, but then I get a warning:

`Warning: Attempt to present <SLFacebookComposeViewController: 0x9471720> on <ViewController: 0xa193f30> while a presentation is in progress!`

Is there a way to detect if a "presentation is in progress" (or rather, if a share sheet is already presented to the user) and wait until it's finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to wait until the user is finished with the twitter post before displaying the facebook dialog. You can code it so that the facebook dialog is displayed in the twitter dialog's completion handler:

```
   if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) //check if Twitter Account is linked
    {
      mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init]; //initiate the Social Controller
        mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]; //Tell him with what social plattform to use it, e.g. facebook or twitter
                [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]]; //the message you want to post
       [mySLComposerSheet addImage:yourimage]; //an image you could post

        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

//  dismiss the Tweet Sheet
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [self shareFacebook];
  }];
});
    }];
```

EDIT: You will need to dismiss the controller first, and call the facebook method AFTER the controller has been dismissed.. You need to dismiss the controller on the main thread because the completion handler is not guaranteed to be called on the main thread.

However, from a UX perspective, it would be quite cumbersome for the user to be forced to share to twitter and Facebook at the same time. Perhaps there's a better way to do this sharing?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Instead, I now get the warning: `Warning: Attempt to present <SLFacebookComposeViewController: 0xa139850>  on <ViewController: 0xa41b6c0> which is already presenting <SLTwitterComposeViewController: 0x10e09730>`

Comment: There's a reason I want to do it this way. Thanks for your help, the edited version worked!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this. But you can use `NSOperationQueue`.